# Не отображается мой код в браузере

Tags: html5

При открытии файла html не отображается код написанный в sublime text[image: вот код]

[image: вот результат]

Comment: Точечка в заголовке намекает, что у вас файл не сохранён

Comment: Правая кнопка мыши => смотреть код => элементы => смотрите. Возможно, у вас нулевые высота или ширина у чего-нибудь.

Comment: @andreymal, причём оба.

Answer (score 0):

Точка (сверху, где название) говорит о том, что вы забыли сохранить файл. Нажмите ctrl + S

Comment: Чужой ответ отправлять - не очень хорошая практика

Comment: @SergeyK. но вполне допустимая, если какие-то вредины ленятся опубликовать ответ самостоятельно